# Custom-view button onDraw() method does not draw

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-button

If I extend a button and override the `onDraw` method to draw something for example a circle and in XML layout file use:

```
<view class = "com.example.button.MainActivity$MyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

the circle appears but if I use this

```
<Button class = "com.example.button.MainActivity$MyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Instead, nothing except the default rectangular view for button appears.
why?
The custom button class implementation is in 
[extending android button by using onDraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573667/extending-android-button-by-using-ondraw)
and the `onDraw()` method is:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();
    canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, height/3, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use an inner class in an xml layout, the syntax is always:

```
<view class = "com.example.button.MainActivity$MyButton"
    ...
/>
```

If you use `<Button ...` the class attribute is ignored, that's why it's inflating and drawing a standard Button widget.

If you want `MyButton` to be a `Button`, just have its class extend it. You don't need to change the xml at all.