# GraphView how to Display Toast near the user click point

Tags: android, android-graphview, android-toast

Hello i would like to ask, how can i Display Toast near the user click point Like on image below using GraphView library:

http://android-graphview.org/

[image]

Thanks for any advice

**EDIT:**

I tried it using

```
seriesSin = new GraphViewSeries("Sinus curve", new GraphViewSeries.GraphViewSeriesStyle(Color.rgb(200, 50, 00), 3), data);

   // SET ON TOUCH
        graphView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    int size = seriesSin.size();
                    float screenX = event.getX();
                    float screenY = event.getY();
                    float width_x = v.getWidth();
                    float viewX = screenX - v.getLeft();
                    float viewY = screenY - v.getTop();
                    float percent_x = (viewX/width_x);
                    int pos = (int) (size*percent_x);

                    System.out.println("X: " + viewX + " Y: " + viewY +" Percent = " +percent_x);
                    System.out.println("YVal = " +seriesSin.getY(pos));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

But I cannot to get seriesSin.size and seriesSin.getY(pos)

Comment: Tricky. You can give a try to `toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);` along with [positions of touch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23411401/1777090)

Comment: Any crash or just getting null values?

Comment: Cannot resolve method getY(pos) and size()

Comment: Ah! I see. Yours is GraphViewSeries. And these are methods of GraphView.

Comment: check if normal method of activity [works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3476840/1777090), then

Comment: Graph is in the fragment. So it writes error Method does not override method from its superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decide where to display the `Toast`. However, you could set up a custom view and show it using the coordinates (x and y) you get when detecting the touch. When you show the view, simply use those values to set up the layout params of the view, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.0.0 added an [onTap() listener](http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/tap-listener-on-data-points), that replicates your onTouch method above, it doesn't solve your Toast positioning issue, but could save you a few lines of code.