# how can I create a custom clickable shape on an image in android?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, shapes

I want to create a clickable image, my image has some different clickable parts in it, like this one:

[image]
I want to draw a custom shape like :
A,B,C,D,E,F
and make sure when user click on of this something happen.
the problem is I don't have any kind of idea to, how create shapes like the shapes in the image make sure it just fix on the image and in different screen size don't see a massed up thing.

Comment: **Simplify** your life: In a RelativeLayout, use this as the background, then put some (normal) rectangular ImageViews on top of this one. A certain approximation is allowed.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap

Comment: yeah this is the easiest way but but bcz the image are some plan the y can have very bad shapes and rectangle and square and circle cant help me.

Comment: Or... do a clickable legend! So you would have some buttons BELOW the floor plan, each with a color background and a letter (i.e.: F, D and B with a pink back, E with a green back and A and C with a blue back). This is even **simpler**!

Comment: In the very end, you could use a real imagemap, contained in a WebView (this solution would also allow for scrollable contents).

Comment: tnx let me check it, it semms usefulllll @ketan-ahir

Comment: yeah it my last plan if i cant create and reach my goal, i do this ;) @der-golem

Comment: @KetanAhir tnx for the link but a probblem:), i just find out android image map just work on fuullll screen, i want show my plan in something like header. can u give me some help about this?

Answer (score 2):

Will there be more than many of such images?

If no I suggest you to create mask image for each region where black part of image represents the region and white part excludes rest.

To draw image:

- create custom [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)
- in constructor don't forget to use [setWillNotDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw(boolean)) to true so you can do custom drawing
- override [View.onDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method where you can draw main image and all others with some [filters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) via [setColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)]).

To handle click events:

- override onTouchEvent method
- [get touch position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476840/2316926)
- compare touch position with [point color in mask image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7807442/2316926)

To optimise:

- create mask image downscaled by some scale factor
- during comparison divide touch position by scale factor

This is not ideal, but solution with vectors is non trivial I think

Comment: let me check android image map and if it didn't work i go this way. but i think this way seems little bit hard and it's take time for me, bcz a have 18 pic,less or more,

Answer (score 1):

Take it as image and setOnclickListner for that image

Comment: tnx but this way can't help i want some clickable area on the image.

Comment: take one layout and set its height width as on which area u want to setonclick.. than just add image in that layout and now setonclick event of whole layout...

Comment: This will not help him also, because you are still working with rectangle region. He needs to Draw region on ImageView and handle click events for each region