# How can I forward touch events from Transparent activity to one below it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, touch-event

I have a tutorial activity which is translucent and it gives instructions on how to use the activity below it.

I want to be able to process these touch inputs in the tutorial but also forward them to the below activity.

Here is the structure. Have my full app actively running in the background.
The tutorial screen is on top and has instructions like tap here. I want to be able to know when the user taps so I can switch to the next tutorial screen but I also want the screen below it to update.

Comment: I guess you will need to implement ShowCaseView .For that you can use following lib https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: @AdarshYadav the OP was clear by saying "activity" not drawing a view on current activity.

Comment: Or it would also work if there was a way to do this to replace tutorial activity with a fragment and put on top of the activity.

Comment: @MikeC You can use it on your tutorial activity. Have a look at the this sample activity https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/sample/SampleActivity.java. I know you were trying to implement same kind of functionality by making activity translucent and implementing touch event, But I suggested you this as it will handle almost every scenarios and exceptions by itself.
I didn't see your code what you tried but I hope this will help you !!!

Comment: or additional MikeC you can implement by creating a base activity and switch fragments over it by using view pager. Yes you were right in that case you need to get the touch point where user touched over screen for performing some set of action on it. Have a look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3476840/1384010 for getting  touch points.