# Android: getting x, y coordinates of a view

Tags: android

I wrote the following code to find out the coordinates of touch point.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                float val = view.getAlpha();
                float xVal = view.getX();
                float yVal = view.getY();
                String message = "Screen height: " + height + ", width: " + width + "\n" +
                        "Alpha Value: " + val + ", x Coordinate: " + xVal + ", y Coordinate: " + yVal;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
```

It turns out to be always returning the fixed value, 32.0 for each x coordinate and y coordinate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android This may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the x and y coordinates via `view.getX()` and `view.getY()` respectively inside the `onTouch()` method, the following worked.

`float xVal = motionEvent.getX();`
`float yVal = motionEvent.getY();`

Comment: This answer may be useful for others in the future