# drag and drop imageview in android and detection position

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, ontouchlistener

I am making an application that drag and drop images. I need to make the user of the app can move an image from one point to another of the screen, for example He will touch the image and drag it to a point on the screen where there is another image, and when both images are superimposed, a message on screen, how could I do it?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you with the drag and drop

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3qr1yK6u3M

To know image position you need to work with the ontouchevent:

[How to get the Touch position in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android)