# Transparent overlay over Android screen?

Tags: java, android

I want to create an overlay over the Android screen from where I can record tap locations (x and y coordinates) but the taps pass through and also hit content underneath.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes possible see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476840/6869086