# Get X and Y coordinates while tapping on ImageView

Tags: android, vector, listener

I am trying to place markers on an image (using `ImageView`), the image doesn't fit the screen so have scroll views for that. I am wondering how I would get with a listener the coordinates when user taps so I can add a marker or text, I am hoping I can do this with a vector.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i think, this can be achived dynamically adding text on imageview. the position of text will be based on the tap position, check out this link to get the position https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android

Comment: I can't i need 15 points, but thank you it was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this library [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) and it has `setOnPhotoTapListener((imageView, x, y)` listener which will give you particular X and Y position.

Here is small snippet of my project,

```
private PhotoView mMap;
mMap.setOnPhotoTapListener((imageView, x, y) ->
                processTap((int) (mOriginalMap.getWidth() * x),
                        (int) (mOriginalMap.getHeight() * y))
);
```