# Go to coordinates and click on, How is it done on android?

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener, ontouch

**How do I click on randomly assigned x and y coordinates on Android?** 
Sorry for my English

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Touch position in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use

```
    val event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, metaState);
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
```